# Export data from HDFS to MySQL but data should be updated before going to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I need to import data from MySQL to HDFS, and I'm doing that with Apache Sqoop. But the thing is I also need to export data from HDFS to MySQL and I need to update one column of these data (that is in HDFS) before moving that data to MySQL, how can I do this?

Comment: what changes you need to made?

Comment: You can update the data in hive itself before exporting it to mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the column directly from hdfs and can store the hive output to HDFS using INSER OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "path" then go with the below sqoop command

```
 sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://master/poc \
--username root \
--table employee \
--export-dir /user/hdfs/mysql/export.txt \
--update-key id \
--update-mode allowinsert \
--fields-terminated-by '\t' \
-m 1
```

Hope this helps..